# TypeScript is not enforcing generic intersection type (React component props)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that accepts a generic type parameter `TChildProps`:

```
type GenericFieldHTMLAttributes =
    | InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
    | SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>
    | TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>

interface FieldProps {
    name: string
    label?: string | React.ReactNode
    component?: string | React.ComponentType
    initialValue?: any
    children?: React.ReactNode | FieldRenderFunction
}

class Field<TChildProps = GenericFieldHTMLAttributes> extends React.PureComponent<FieldProps & TChildProps> {
    ...
}
```

When I use this component, I would expect it to prevent me from passing in unrecognized props, for example:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={this.save}>
            <Field foo="test" label="email" name="email" type="email" component={TextField} />
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Surprisingly, the above code compiles without even any warnings, despite the fact that the `foo` prop is not defined anywhere. I tried simplifying the example and got the same result:

```
class Field<TChildProps = {}> extends React.PureComponent<FieldProps & TChildProps> {
    ...
}

// this still compiles without errors
<Field foo="test" label="email" name="email" type="email" component={TextField} />
```

Is TypeScript functioning the way it's supposed to here according to the type definition for `React.PureComponent` (by the way I tested it on `React.Component` and got the same result), or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer**

Because `<TChildProps = {}>` means that the default value of `TChildProps` is `{}` if the consumer does not assigns any value to `TChilProps`. So `TChildProps` can actually be anything if the consumer decides to pass value to it. That's why typescript allows any props passed to `Field`. What you want to do is to enforce the type of `TChildProps` using `extends` keyword. So try `class Field<TChildProps extends GenericFieldHTMLAttributes>` instead. As a result, the consumer needs to pass `TChildProps` as `GenericFieldHTMLAttributes` type. You can find more information on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html.

**UPDATE**

Here's the simplified situation (**UPDATE2**: I tend to think this is either a bug or a missing feature, here's why)

This `Animal` class below accepting food as generics reflects `React.Component` class that accepts props as generics.

```
class Animal<F> {
  eat(food: F) {
    return;
  }
}
```

And the `Lion` class below extending `Animal` reflects your `Field` class which extends `React.Component`

```
class Lion<F = {pizza: string}> extends Animal<F> {

}
```

And when the consumers consume it, if they do not specify what food a lion should eat, <s>the lion can eat anything like so</s> we should expect the lion to eat only pizza

```
const lion1 = new Lion();
lion1.eat(""); // Argument of  type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type '{pizza: string}'
```

However this type check does not happen in case of tsx.

The workaround is to "alias both the type and interface to a non-generic specialization."

```
const TextField = Field as { new (): Field<{value: string}>};

<TextField foo="test" label="email" name="email" type="email" value="asdf"/> // error: Property 'foo' does not exist
```

These two links should give you more info on how to use generic components as of now.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3960
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/generics.html#generics-in-tsx

And apparently they [working on](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6395) this.

### UPDATE April 2018

This should be possible in Typescript 2.9 as seen in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22415.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your answer and the info on `extends`, but I just wanted `GenericFieldHTMLAttributes` to be a default; I want to give the consumer the option to pass a completely different type if they want (e.g. the props for a datepicker component). I will play around with `extends` to see if I can come up with a solution...

Comment: Now that I think about it more, this answer doesn't make sense. In my example, I'm not passing anything into the generic `TChildProps` type, so it should just be using the default type `GenericFieldHTMLAttributes` or, in my simpler test, just an empty object - both of these definitely do not include a property called `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, very helpful! (Actually I consider your update the real answer; the part at the top could be labeled 'Original Answer', but that's just a minor suggestion.) It seems like there might be an additional issue here besides the inconvenient workaround for using generics in TSX...namely that TSX is ignoring the default parameter value of the generic, which I think should work regardless. I might file a bug report for this in the TypeScript repo if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: FYI I think the basarat.gitbooks.io page might have been reorganized...in any case here's a current link to the specific issue at hand: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/generics.html#generics-in-tsx